# Features importance in model

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, machine-learning-model, feature-importances

I've been using azure's auto ML platform for a couple of weeks now and recently I've trained a model and came across a strange looking aggregate feature importance chart in the explanations tab. The most important feature has an importance of 3,54 while the second one has 0,304. The model shows a good performance but should the chart be this concentrated on only one feature? I tried searching for the algorithm it uses to calculate those numbers hoping to get a grasp of how the ideal chart would look like, but I didn't find any specific documentation on this.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can check the correlation among the features to determine their importance.

Comment: The main question is if a model with this such an imbalanced feature importance is actually viable or if this is a sign of a potential problem rising when using it in new data